# SSIS: how to add one row to data from flat file source's data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Suppose I have flat file source with data

```
Col1 | Col2
A    | 123
B    | 213
```

and I want to add one row with values (C, 1321). How can I do it QUICKLY?

I know I can create new file with this one row, load it to flat file source and use UNION for it. But I want to create in SIMPLY way:).... just like insert to flat file source's data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click on the Flat file destination transformation in the Data Flow and untick "Overwrite data in the file" checkbox. This allows the textfile to be extended. Note: You might need to include a File System Task to delete this file at sometime otherwise this file will extend endlessly!

Comment: So I have to first  "load data from file", second "use Flat File Destination to save data to file" and use once again " load data from file" to get data with one additional record?

Comment: Correct! This will continue to extend the file unless you delete it.

Comment: ...yes... So I would prepare something which is working on data taken from flat file, thanks for solution.